# remove data inside the key in SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

im using flutter 2.8.1 and shared_preferences: ^2.0.13

i build a todoapp with sharedpreferences all works fine from storing data to localstorage and load the data in initState but now i want to delete spesific item/selected item in the localstorage but when i use `prefs.remove('key');` all the item is removed, i only want to remove the selected item only.

let me know if you need more information with the code.

the key contain this, for example i want to remove item with id: 64, not the key

```
I/flutter ( 9643): [{"id":64,"set_name":"asd"},{"id":55,"set_name":"asdasdwqe"}]
```

remove function code

```
    Future deleteData() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.remove('sets');
    setState(() {});
  }
```

save function code

```
 Future saveData() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    List items = c.setList.map((item) => item.toJson()).toList();
    prefs.setString('sets', jsonEncode(items));
  }
```

Comment: Can try checking all keys are unique and  can you include your insert method?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't easy way but to overwrite new values over old value. This is one of the drawbacks of using SharedPreferences over traditional databases.

You will have to read the data from sharedPrefs, remove the concerned value and save it back to sharedPrefs.

Comment: so its better to input unique key and delete the key instead of deleting data inside the key ?

Comment: well because of your explanation i the way to fix it, thanks
- i delete the spesific item and key then i store the item again to localstorage